# Txt to treeView

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to generate a tree view using text file in c#. But I am unable to apply the concept. Would you please tell me how to do it? The txt file contains the following: Separately separated:

Separator =( , ) Parents =Capital letters. Child =Lowercase letters.

A , a, b, c

B, d, e, f

C, g, h, q

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Pseudo code** would look like this

```
foreach line in fileLines
{
    lineNodes = line.Split(", ")
    newParentNode = tree.Nodes.Add(new Node(lineNodes[0]))
    newParentNode.Children.Add(new Node(lineNodes[1]))
    newParentNode.Children.Add(new Node(lineNodes[2]))
    newParentNode.Children.Add(new Node(lineNodes[3]))
}
```

Now, you can use c# specific syntax to implement your home work

Comment: Thank you, this method did not work

Comment: Please, Check my avatar